# Finding which points lie within buffered area using R?

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I am trying to set up a script to find whether a point on a trajectory comes within a certain distance of a polygon. For context, I am using two data sets: the first is the result of a HYSPLIT model, showing air trajectories and where that air parcel is expected to be at a certain time. The second is a data frame of ZIP code centroids within a county.

My aim is to know if a point crosses the buffer for the the ZIP code centroid, and if so, which ZIP code was it and at what point in time did that occur?

```
traj <- data.frame(
    hour = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23),
    lat = c(33.176, 33.236, 33.304, 33.397, 33.536, 33.693, 33.850, 34.011,
            34.181, 34.382, 34.612, 34.825, 35.025, 35.210, 35.382, 35.511, 
            35.558, 35.640, 35.715, 35.795, 35.845, 35.885, 35.918, 35.927),
    lon = c(-115.623, -115.488, -115.322, -115.132, -114.938, -114.787, -114.699, 
            -114.640, -114.561, -114.472, -114.399,-114.324, -114.207, -114.050, 
            -113.794, -113.280, -112.605, -111.907, -111.230, -110.708, -110.036, 
            -109.314, -108.520, -107.810),
    date = c(2012-03-01 00:00:00, 2012-03-01 01:00:00, 2012-03-01 02:00:00, 2012-03-01 03:00:00, 
             2012-03-01 04:00:00, 2012-03-01 05:00:00, 2012-03-01 06:00:00, 2012-03-01 07:00:00, 
             2012-03-01 08:00:00, 2012-03-01 09:00:00, 2012-03-01 10:00:00, 2012-03-01 11:00:00, 
             2012-03-01 12:00:00, 2012-03-01 13:00:00, 2012-03-01 14:00:00, 2012-03-01 15:00:00, 
             2012-03-01 16:00:00, 2012-03-01 17:00:00, 2012-03-01 18:00:00, 2012-03-01 19:00:00,
             2012-03-01 20:00:00, 2012-03-01 21:00:00)
)

#Convert hysplit data frame to an sf object
traj.sf <- st_as_sf(traj, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs=4326)
traj.sf
plot(traj.sf$geometry)


#Create the same dataframe for median pop centroids

medpop <- data.frame(
  longitude = c(-116.305303, -115.524899, -115.497389, -115.514936, 
                -115.566751, -115.505786, -115.361211, -115.575202, 
                -115.535597, -115.993063, -114.73435, -115.692165, 
                -116.040401, -115.956263, -115.621221, -114.628562), 
  latitude = c(33.211896, 32.980541, 32.680197, 33.127061, 
               32.784691, 32.729742, 32.807613, 32.848569, 
               33.280736, 32.734248, 33.372017, 32.795324, 
               33.409293, 33.289944, 33.039245, 32.77435), 

  Name = c("92004", "92227", "92231", "92233", "92243", "92249", "92250", "92251", 
           "92257", "92259", "92266", "92273", "92274", "92275", "92281", "92283"))
medpop

#convert the population centroid points data frame to an sf object
centroids <- st_as_sf(medpop, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs=4326)
centroids

#Buffer the points
buffers <- st_buffer(centroids, dist = 0.2)

#Finding points within centroid buffers
over <- st_intersects(buffers, traj.sf)
```

I have attempted to use st_intersects from the sf package. The issue I am running into is that R appears to be returning a list of objects, but I actually need to know when the intersect occurred and which ZIP code the point actually comes near.

I am a novice user of R as a GIS, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What package is hysplit from?

Comment: HYSPLIT is a meteorological model, but the package I am using to run the model in R is called SplitR. Editing the script to show that.

Comment: Always try to limit your question to your problem so that you get the best answer. At the moment your question is too long. Is that the last line you are troubled with?

Comment: Yes, the last line is what seems to give me just a list, but what I'd like to be able to see is the location of the points when they intersect and at what point in time (all variables within the data frames).

Comment: In that case, reformulate your question to reflect this that, and some simple example data. See the R help files or questions on this website on how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, and close...

You will need to make use of the `sparse = F` setting of `sf::st_intersects` to get back a vector, and then use it to subset your `centroids` data frame.

I am plotting the results, I expect that the red points (centroids of the buffers that have been intersected by the trajectory) are what you are after...

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

traj <- data.frame(
  hour = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23),
  lat = c(33.176, 33.236, 33.304, 33.397, 33.536, 33.693, 33.850, 34.011,
          34.181, 34.382, 34.612, 34.825, 35.025, 35.210, 35.382, 35.511, 
          35.558, 35.640, 35.715, 35.795, 35.845, 35.885, 35.918, 35.927),
  lon = c(-115.623, -115.488, -115.322, -115.132, -114.938, -114.787, -114.699, 
          -114.640, -114.561, -114.472, -114.399,-114.324, -114.207, -114.050, 
          -113.794, -113.280, -112.605, -111.907, -111.230, -110.708, -110.036, 
          -109.314, -108.520, -107.810))

#Convert hysplit data frame to an sf object
traj.sf <- st_as_sf(traj, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs=4326)


#Create the same dataframe for median pop centroids

medpop <- data.frame(
  longitude = c(-116.305303, -115.524899, -115.497389, -115.514936, 
                -115.566751, -115.505786, -115.361211, -115.575202, 
                -115.535597, -115.993063, -114.73435, -115.692165, 
                -116.040401, -115.956263, -115.621221, -114.628562), 
  latitude = c(33.211896, 32.980541, 32.680197, 33.127061, 
               32.784691, 32.729742, 32.807613, 32.848569, 
               33.280736, 32.734248, 33.372017, 32.795324, 
               33.409293, 33.289944, 33.039245, 32.77435), 

  Name = c("92004", "92227", "92231", "92233", "92243", "92249", "92250", "92251", 
           "92257", "92259", "92266", "92273", "92274", "92275", "92281", "92283"))
#convert the population centroid points data frame to an sf object
centroids <- st_as_sf(medpop, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs=4326)

#Buffer the points
buffers <- st_buffer(centroids, dist = .2)

#Finding points within centroid buffers
over <- centroids[st_intersects(buffers, traj.sf, sparse = F)[,1], ]
over

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = over, col = "red") +
  geom_sf(data = traj.sf, pch = 4, col = "gray40") +
  geom_sf(data = buffers, fill = NA) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! Of note for any who have the same issue: st_intersection will give a data frame of all of the buffers that are crossed by a point, whereas the above answer, using st_intersects, gives what appears to be the unique values.

Answer (score 0):

using the function st_intersection rather than st_intersects solves this problem. This returns a data frame rather than a list:

`````
over <- st_intersection(bufers, traj.sf) 
### the polygon, followed by the points that might cross the polygon

````
`````